# PHP foreach array redundant

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

The foreach array I have here is redundant.  The problem I'm having is that  if(empty($theone['bans'])) checks if the array is not there, then continues.  Then, if the array exists, foreach ($theone['bans'] as $ban) and the code is the same if the array is empty.  How can I shorten this?

```
<?php
foreach ($finder['zigzag'] as $zigzag)
{
    foreach ($zigzag as $theone)
    {  
        if(empty($theone['bans']))
        {
            if($theone['total'] >= $theone['limit'])
            {
                echo 'full';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '
                    <form action="" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" name="login" value="" class="input" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php e($room['id']) ?>" />
                     </form>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($theone['bans'] as $ban)
            {
                if ($finder['profile']['ip'] == $ban['ip'])
                {
                    echo 'Banned user';
                }
                elseif ($theone['total'] >= $theone['limit'])
                {
                    echo 'full';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '
                    <form action="" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" name="login" value="" class="input" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php e($room['id']) ?>" />
                     </form>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the php tags from the start and end of each line, and just have them at the start and end of the code?

Comment: It's more of the !empty($theone['bans']

Comment: Your code is almost unreadable with this opening and closing tags. Also, I suggest using curly brackets instead of `foreach (): endforeach` and `if (): endif`. It would make your code much cleaner and easy looking. If you update your code after formatting it will be easier to refactor your code logic.

Comment: who tricked you into putting `<?php` / `?>` each line?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach ($finder['zigzag'] as $zigzag){
    foreach ($zigzag as $theone){  
        if(isset($theone['bans'])){
            foreach ($theone['bans'] as $ban){
                if ($finder['profile']['ip'] == $ban['ip']){
                    echo 'Banned user';}}}
        else{
            if ($theone['total'] >= $theone['limit']){
                echo 'full';}
            else{
                echo '
                    <form action="" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" name="login" value="" class="input" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$room['id'].'" />
                    </form>';}}}}
?>
```

this will check to see if the array has been set...

```
if(isset($theone['bans']))
```

depending on how your arrays have been defined you may need to try something like

```
 if($theone['bans']!='')
```

Comment: Okay, done The foreach array I have here is redundant. The problem I'm having is that if(empty($theone['bans'])) checks if the array is not there, then continues. Then, if the array exists, foreach ($theone['bans'] as $ban) and the code is the same if the array is empty. How can I shorten this?

Comment: sorry for the delay... I think I understand what you mean, I will edit my answer